# How can I create an eager observable from a hot observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

AFAIK, observable is lazy.

```
import * as rxjs from 'rxjs'
const { filter, take, map } = rxjs.operators

function awesomeOpators() {
  return take(1);
}

const numbers$ = new rxjs.Subject<number>();
const start$ = numbers$.pipe(
  awesomeOpators(),
);


numbers$.next(1);

start$.subscribe((val) => {
  // outputs 2
  console.log(val)
})

numbers$.next(2)
```

How can I rewrite `awesomeOpators` such that `beginWithLargeNumbe$` starts with 1?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zqkz7r?file=main.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ReplaySubject instead:

```
const numbers$ = new rxjs.ReplaySubject<number>();
```

There's a bunch of other ways as well. You haven't told us which part you can or can't control, though, so this will do.

Comment: Yeah, ReplaySubject should work. But I want to know how to pipe `numbers$` such that `start$` starts with 1.

Comment: Just multicast it through a separate ReplaySubject then which you immediately connect. You have to connect before the first value is emitted, otherwise the value is just lost.

Comment: I've updated my question. Can you please tell me what code I should put into `function awesomeOpators`?